# How to get average scores of other persons in Cognos Dashboard

Tags: dashboard, cognos

I was asked to create Cognos dashboard graph(s) and display the score and the Average Scores of other persons. Let's say, 7 persons got Scores as below. Could any one help me find a calculation expression for 3rd column to get the average scores from other persons. Thanks.

```
Name     Score      Average Scores of Other Persons

Andrew      95                   
Billy       85                                      
Charlie     75                                      
Danny       80                   
Edward      90                   
Frank      100                    
Garry       70  


As total score is 595, therefore, 
Andrew's 3rd column would be (595-95)/6 = 83
Billy's 3rd column would be (595-85)/6 = 85
.......
```

Comment: Have the obvious expressions not worked?

Where does the 6 come from, given that you have 7 records?

Comment: The 3rd column is "Average Scores of other persons", Since we have 7 persons, 6 is the number of other persons.

Comment: OK, that part would be (count (name) -1) but what expressions have you tried and what results have you gotten?

Comment: I tried (Total (Score) - Score)/(Count(name) - 1)  and got the same value as Score.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

(total([Score] for report)-[Score])/(count[Name]-1)

Comment: It works after adding 'for report' portion. Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[Total Count] = data item to get the count

```
Count([Name] for report)
```

[Total Score] = data item for the total

```
Total([Score] for report)
```

[Average Score] = data item for the third column

```
([Total Score]-[Score])/([Total Count] -1)
```